# How a child serializer can access a respective field value from its parent serializer initalized with many=True?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In case we want to initialize the parent serializer with `many=True`, then how can the child serializer can access a respective field value from its parent serializer?

```py
class ChildSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    field1 = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        # How to get the value of batch_key from the parent serializer (here self.batch_key)?
        if not self.batch_key == data['field1']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('invalid field1')
        return data


class ParentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    child = ChildSerializer(many=True)
    batch_key = serializers.CharField()


class MyAPIView(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ParentSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return
```

request data is as follows:

```
[
   {
      "batch_key":"batch_key_value_1",
      "child":[
         {
            "field1":"value1"
         },
         {
            "field1":"value2"
         },
         {
            "field1":"value3"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "batch_key":"batch_key_value_2",
      "child":[
         {
            "field1":"value4"
         },
         {
            "field1":"value5"
         },
         {
            "field1":"value6"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach is to do [**`object-level validation..[DRF-docs]`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation) where you run all the validation you need from the parent serializer, since you have access to both the batch key, and the child data.

So something like this:

```py
class ParentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    child = ChildSerializer(many=True)
    batch_key = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        for child in data["child"]:
            if child["field1"] != data["batch_key"]:
                raise serializers.ValidationError({
                    "child": {
                        "field1": f"Invalid field1 {child['field1']}"
                    }
                })

        return data
```

This also works when `ParentSerializer` has `many=True`. This is not perfect, as it doesn't separate the errors per child, so leaving it to you for exercise ;)

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the batch_key value to ChildSerialzier from ParentSerilaizer and in `__init__` of the child serailizer set self.batch_key value .

Answer (score 0):

We can use `parent` and `initial_data` in serializer.

```
class ChildSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    field1 = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        parent = self.parent   # will get rest_framework.serializers.ListSerializer  because many=True
        parent_serializer = parent.parent
        initial_data = parent_serializer.initial_data
        
        batch_key = initial_data=.get("batch_key", None)
        ...
```

**NOTE !!!** Cons using `initial_data` it mean that data not valid yet.
Other solutions, no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [custom ListSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-listserializer-behavior) to pass on the value to `ChildSerializer`.

### Option 1

Set `batch_key` as a property on the `ChildSerializer` instance. Note that this instance is shared across all the values of the list.

Caveat: `self.batch_key` used in the `ChildSerializer` isn't validated and might contain invalid values.

```py
class CustomListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def get_value(self, dictionary):
        # `dictionary` is the data passed from the parent.
        # The return value of this function will be passed to `run_validation`.
        value = dictionary.get(self.field_name, empty)
        batch_key = dictionary.get("batch_key")
        return {"value": value, "batch_key": batch_key}

    def run_validation(self, data=empty):
        # Set "batch_key" that was returned by `get_value` above.
        #
        # `self.child` refers to the `ChildSerializer` instance. This instance
        # will be common for all the items in the list.
        self.child.batch_key = None
        if data is not empty and data is not None:
            self.child.batch_key = data["batch_key"]
            # Extract the value expected by the original `run_validation`.
            data = data["value"]
        return super().run_validation(data)


class ChildSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    field1 = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        # `CustomListSerializer` will be used for all the `many=True` instances
        # of the `ChildSerializer`.
        list_serializer_class = CustomListSerializer

    def validate(self, data):
        if self.batch_key != data["field1"]:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("invalid field1")
        return data
```

---

### Option 2

Set `batch_key` as a field of `ChildSerializer` as well, with appropriate validators. This will ensure that `ChildSerializer.validate` won't be called with invalid values of `batch_key`.

This has another issue though, in case of invalid values, `batch_key` will show up multiple times in `parent.errors`: once for the `ParentSerializer`, and again for every element in the children array. This can be fixed as well, if you're using `.errors` as it is.

```py
class CustomListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def get_value(self, dictionary):
        value = dictionary.get(self.field_name, empty)
        if isinstance(value, list):
            batch_key = dictionary.get("batch_key")
            # Add "batch_key" to each item of the list. Each item will be individually
            # validated by the `ChildSerializer`.
            value = [{"batch_key": batch_key, **v} for v in value]
        return value


class ChildSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    field1 = serializers.CharField()
    batch_key = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = CustomListSerializer

    def validate(self, data):
        # Instead of `self.batch_key`...
        if data["batch_key"] != data["field1"]:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("invalid field1")
        return data
```